# How to set C# winform control's location relative to the top right corner of the form?

Tags: c#, winforms

As you know when you set the location property of a control to (0, 0), the top-left corner of the control will sit at the top-left corner of the form.

How can I set this property relative to the top-right corner of the form?

(The control needs to be located to by its top-right corner also.)

I've set the RightToLeftLayout to true but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: with winforms just set the anchors

Answer (score 2):

*Way 1*. Move element to top-right location of form and set property [Anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?view=netframework-4.8) to Top, Right in designer or in the code:

`controlInstance.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right;`

*Way 2*. Using [Dock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock?view=netframework-4.8) property.

Add panel and set Dock property in ***Top***. Add control to panel and set Dock property  of control to ***Right***. For this case, it is better to layout all the form elements with the Dock property.